# import data from excel - . (dot) in column name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, import

**Update--------**

I am trying to import data from excel sheet. Everything is fine, except, Column name have '**.**'

```
 selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Date,[Meter No.] FROM [Advance EDS export$]";
```

This column is creating issue **[Meter No.]**

Comment: I have an Excel sheet with spaces in its name and the syntax above works for me.

Comment: @yes, it works to me. Finally I figured out the issue, issue is in column name, I just update my quesiton.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer myself. When we import data from excel, if it has a **.** in the column name, it will automatically convert to **#**

For instance in my case, the original column is **[Meter No.]** in excel, but it converted to **[Meter No#]** so finally, it looks like...

```
selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Date,[Meter No#] FROM [Advance EDS export$]";
```

I used the `select *` in command text and then check the imported datatable and found it that way.

Comment: What data provider are you using that causes this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to escape such characters if you put all the names into square brackets...

```
 selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT [Date],[Meter No.] FROM [Advance EDS export$]";
```

similar question: [msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/8fa4a564-395e-48d5-8cfc-22bafcbb4628/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a quote for such names.

```
selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Date,c1 FROM ['Advance EDS export$']";
```